# Perl sprintf format number with leading zeros and 2 decimals

Tags: perl, printf

In Perl, I'd like to format a value with 2 leading zeros and two decimal places.
e.g.

```
00.41
```

Using something like this doesn't work:

```
$dist = sprintf ("%2.2f", $dist);
```

What would be the correct format?

Comment: And if the value is > 1, do you still want two leading zeroes? E.g. `12` becomes `0012.00`

Comment: No, if the values is > 1, then just a leading zero.
e.g. - 5.69 would be "05.69" and 
         23.45 would simply be "23.45"
...so basically 2 leading positions padded with zeros and 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can force the whole string to have a certain width, and tell it to pad it with zeros.  This would work since you want fixed (two) decimal places

```
my $str = sprintf "%05.2f", $num;
```

If the number ends up larger than this width (`123.45`, six places) you'll still see the whole number.

If the number indeed can be larger you can first work out the needed width, if you always want two extra leading zeros.

---

Or, since that's going to be a string anyway, just prepend a `0` once you format the number

```
my $str = '0' . sprintf "%.2f", $num;
```

or, really, just

```
my $str = sprintf "0%.2f", $num;
```

If two zeros need be added use `'00'`.  That's about the only advantage of this over `sprintf "%0${wd}.2f` (where you work out the needed width `$wd`, or have it be a flat `5` if that's always it) -- that you can just slap as many zeros as you want.

Note that in all this the extra leading zero will go away if you do any numerics with it.